# How to display unicode in web page (tweepy/python/django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unicode, tweepy

So I've read a ton of SO questions and can't figure out how to solve this frustrating encoding issue.

I am using Tweepy to pull some tweets, then passing the tweet text to HTML via a Django view. My problem is that while SOME emoji's/Non-ASCII characters work, I still get some weird characters, specifically ampersands get displayed as `&amp;` and some emojis show up as .

Here's the flow of the Tweet text from Python to initial HTML display:

find_tweets.py:

```
def find_tweets():
    results = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query).items(50)]
    selected_tweets = []
    for tweet in results:
        #### Some condition
        selected_tweets.append({
            'user_screen_name': tweet.user.screen_name,
            'user_profile_image_url': tweet.user.profile_image_url,
            'text': tweet.text,
            'user_followers_count': tweet.user.followers_count,
            'id': tweet.id,
            'user_id': tweet.user.id,
            'user_name': tweet.user.name})
    return selected_tweets
```

views.py Just sends one tweet at a time to the HTML:

```
def view_search:
    tweets = find_tweets()
    to_render = {### Some other dict key/value pairs
                 'tweet': tweets[0]}
    return render(request, 
                  'search_results.html', 
                  to_render,)
```

search_results.html simply calls the tweet with:

```
<div class="tweet-text">
    <p>{{ tweet.text }}</p>
</div>
```

I've tried different combinations of encode('utf-8') and decode('utf-8') in the python code and view, but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure your database handles UTF-8 correctly?

Comment: I'm using the standard Django/SQLite setup (so you could def be right), but this is all happening pre-database. I can actually get the error when I run find_tweets by itself, and the only data structures I'm using are lists and dicts.